# little preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i made a function to get the .php file path and strip everything out but the name of the file, so i could load my css & js files for the pages separately. this is for another function i made to load the top and bottom parts of the page, so i could do something like this: print main_top() . $html . main_bottom(); at the bottom of every page and just require the page these function reside in. <-- kinda like tbdev does...

i got it to work, but when it hits something like this, <3  it will not return the name i want.
i know my problem is in the regex, but im not skilled at regex, i was wondering if anyone here knew if (a) the regex was good, meaning not full of holes or w/e and (b) if anyone knew of a way to make it match chars like: < > & and so on..

```
$filename = preg_replace("/\?([A-Za-z1-9=&_0-9\-\?]+)/", " ", $filename);

$filename = preg_replace("/\?([A-Za-z]+)=(.+?)/U", " ", $filename);
```

again, the function works great, except for when i search and there are chars like that in the $_GET part of the address. hope i make sense here... LoL

the regex was made by me and not lifted off a site somewhere, so if it's crap, i will understand...l LoL

Answer (score 3):

> i made a function to get the .php file
> path and strip everything out but the
> name of the file

This sounds like exactly what `basename` ( https://www.php.net/basename ) does without all the regex.

Comment: thanks for the tip, it worked till i got to a url with $_GET info in it.        $filename = preg_replace("/\?(.+?)/U", " ", $filename);  <-- this is working though and im not having a problem with it yet. is there any problems with this? im not display it or inserting it in to the database, so i should be good right? thanks for reading... ;0)